Sagging Attic Baffles? Need to Address?
So I recently bought a new home, and I was checking out the attic more closely for the first time. I noticed that the plastic baffles in my aren't vertical against the roofline, but rather are sagging and sitting more horizontally on the insulation. No idea long it has been this way, or if they added insulation at some point. Imgur link for reference picture.

So my question is - how concerned should I be about this? There are no apparent moisture problems in the attic, and I'd assume the warm air rising through my soffit vents will eventually rise to the apex of roofline whether the air is being directed vertically by perfectly installed baffles or not. Any thoughts?
Imgur Link

The baffles are to stop blocking of air from the soffits.  If air can flow from the soffits into the attic, then it should be good.

Thank you @crip659!

The part of the baffle that matters is between the roof and the end of the insulation, which should be maintaining an open air passage to the soffit vent (which is, normally, a cool air intake .vs. the hot or warm attic air, which is what you want to leave out the top vents.)
So long as that's open, the part that fell off the roof and onto the insulation does not matter, though it doesn't say much for the installation. They could have been cut off flush with the insulation (but usually are not, in case you come back and add more insulation - plus it's not usually a long enough piece to be useful.)

Thanks @Ecnerwal. This seems to match the advice I'm getting from some other sources as well... likely not an issue so long as there's air flow and no signs of moisture up there (which seems to be the case). I'll continue to monitor and will likely correct/re-staple these when I get around to adding some more insulation up there. I appreciate the advice!
